# Show also content on users view

Tags: views, users

I have a Drupal View that was created to show users which are members of the site, this works fine but now the client wants to see not only users on the same view, but also content of type "X", but when I try to add the ***Filter Criteria*** for ***Content type = X*** , that Filter is not available (don't know why I can't see it), I don't know if this is related to the fact that this was a view created to show Users and not Content from the very beginning.

My question is, what would be the way (hopefully the easiest) to show not only users but also content of Type "X" on my view ? I don't need any logic between the user and the content, is just show on the view results Users and Content of type "X".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does content type X relate to the user, are you trying to show a user and content type X that was created by that user?  What format do you intend to display this info?

Comment: No, there's no relationship between them, I just need all users and all content of type "X" to be listed, and the i'll create some exposed filters but yeah, there's no real relationship between them (since I could create a View Relationship).

Answer (score 0):

What about just creating two different views, one for users and another one for content? If there is no relationship between users and content, this might be the easiest solution.

You can create two different blocks and then display them together in your page (using Blocks, Context, Panels or whatever method you prefer).

Hope it helps,